# why the errors are thrown when code is not placed in main block

Tags: java

I am implementing a Stack
Here is my code for that
package data_structure;

```
public class Stack
 { 
  private int top;
  private int max;
  private int[] data;
  Stack(int s)
   {
     max=s;
     data=new int[s];
     top=-1;
   }
  public void push(int a)
    {
     data[++top]=a;
    }
  public int pop()
    {
     return data[top--];
    }
  public int peek()
   {
    return data[top];     
   }
  public boolean isEmpty()
   { 
    if (top==-1)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
   }
 }
```

I am using it another class

```
package data_structure; 
class StackImplementation 
 {

    Stack abc =new Stack(5);
    boolean value = abc.isEmpty();
    if(value==true)
      {
         System.out.println("Yes it's empty");
      }
    abc.push(22);
    abc.push(23);
  }
```

Stack Implementation is throwing compilation error like Illegal start of type at if(value==true)
identifier expected at(value ==true) and some more error which got removed if the whole code is placed under main method.

Comment: your class is lacking a method that executes this code. You can declare and even assign the fields inside the class, but if you want to execute code, you'll either have to do it within a constructor or (preferably) inside a method / getter / setter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error is simply because you didn't wrap your code in a method.

```
if(value==true)
```

at this point the compiler doesn't expect an if statement.

```
class StackImplementation {
  public void foo () {
    Stack abc =new Stack(5);
    boolean value = abc.isEmpty();
    if(value)
      {
         System.out.println("Yes it's empty");
      }
    abc.push(22);
    abc.push(23);
 }
}
```

Note that you can also skip the `== true` part in your condition because you already have a `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement and `abc.push(22);abc.push(23);` must be in method. If you don't want to create the method then use  block like this

```
class StackImplementation 
 {

    Stack abc =new Stack(5);
     boolean value = abc.isEmpty();
     {
         if(value==true)
         {
             System.out.println("Yes it's empty");
         }
         abc.push(22);
         abc.push(23);
     }

  }
```